# loop inside loop in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

i got a JSON file with an array like this

```
"vars": [
                  {
                     "key": "f1",
                     "link": "@cooldownchampion",
                     "coeff": [
                        24,
                        23,
                        22,
                        21,
                        20
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "key": "f4",
                     "link": "@text",
                     "coeff": [
                        150,
                        175,
                        200,
                        225,
                        250,
                        275,
                        300,
                        325,
                        350,
                        375,
                        400,
                        425,
                        450,
                        475,
                        500,
                        525,
                        550,
                        575
                     ]
                  }
               ]
```

i want do loop inside loop to get all the entry for coeff

this is my loop

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in newjson["vars"]{
   for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in newjson["vars"][key]["coeff"]{
      print (subJson) // this should print 24/23/22/21 but it doesn't
}

}
```

as you know that i use SWIFTYJSON library for handle JSON FILE

Comment: So what does it print instead?

Comment: // this should print 24/23/22/21 but it doesn't ,, just empty

Comment: You need to use the `array` property when your JSON key is associated to an array. Similarly, you need to use the right properties to get optionals for the expected type (ej `.int`, `.string`, etc). `newjson["vars"].array` for example.

Comment: try newjson["vars"] ... newjson["vars"][0] .... etc find a bug . YourSWIFTYJSON syntax is wrong. are you sure about value of key? the index in newjson["vars"][index] is not the the same as the key from the (key,value) pair ....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your first `key` is a `String` and to access to an element by index need an `Int`.

You can fix the problem by casting:

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in newjson["vars"] {
    for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in newjson["vars"][Int(key)!]["coeff"]{
        print (subJson) // this should print 24/23/22/21 but it doesn't
    }
}
```

But a better way would be to use the existing JSON object (`subJson`) like this:

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in newjson["vars"] {
    for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in subJson["coeff"]{
        print (subJson) // this should print 24/23/22/21 but it doesn't
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alexandre Perez I didn't see you answer, sorry for 'duplication'

Comment: i want but 

Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post ...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in newjson["vars"]{
   for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in newjson["vars"][indexInTheArray]["coeff"]{
      print (subJson) // this should print 24/23/22/21 but it doesn't
}

}
```

you are indexing the array with with key:String, the indexInTheArray should be an integer

Answer (score -1):

i don't know how to code with swift

if use object-c

```
NSArray *vars = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"vars"];

for (NSDictionary *dict in vars) {

   NSString *key = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];

   NSArray *coeff = [dict objectForKey:@"coeff"];

}
```

Comment: thank you but for real i can't start OBJECT-C ^^" and i can't embed this code inside my swift code :(